# Zibonacci recursive, what's wrong with my solution?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, fibonacci

I followed the rules but I still get stack-overflow for n>2.

This function borrows ideas from the Fibonacci series, but the calculated results appear to zig and zag, hence the name. A so-called 'Zibonacci' series would be defined by the following rules:

```
Zib(0) == 1;
Zib(1) == 1;
Zib(2) == 2;
Zib(2n+1) == Zib(n) + Zib(n-1)+1, if n>0 (i.e. odd values 3 and higher)
Zib(2n) == Zib(n) + Zib(n+1)+1, if n>1 (i.e. even values 4 and higher).
```

Create the Zibonacci(num) function.

My solution:

```
function Zibonacci(num){
    // Enter code below
    if(num == 0){
       return 1;
    }
    if(num == 1 || num == 2){
       return num;
    }
    if(num>0 && num%2 != 0){
       return Zibonacci(num) + Zibonacci(num-1)+1;
    }
    if(num>1 && num%2 == 0){
       return Zibonacci(num) + Zibonacci(num+1)+1;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Take a debugger (or pen and paper) and go step by step with `Zibonacci(3)`. What happens ? (If you go pen and paper, follow exactly your code, not what you think it does)

Comment: Note in your description it says Zib(**2n+1**) == Zib(**n**) + Zib(**n-1**)+1; that's not what you implemented in your code. The same applies to `Zib(2n)`

Comment: My mistake, I thought Zib(2n+1) was the formula for odd numbers and was equivalent to: 

if(num%2 != 0){ 
Zib(n) + Zib(n-1)+1;
 }

I need more practice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll first need to reformulate the recursive equations to derive Z(n) instead of Z(2n+1) and Z(2n):

- Zib(n) == Zib((n - 1) / 2) + Zib((n - 1) / 2 - 1) + 1, if n>0 (i.e. odd values 3 and higher)
- Zib(n) == Zib(n / 2) + Zib(n / 2 + 1) + 1, if n>1 (i.e. even values 4 and higher).

This leads to code like this:

```js
function Zibonacci(num){
    if (num == 0) {
       return 1;
    }
    if (num == 1 || num == 2) {
       return num;
    }
    if (num > 0 && num % 2 != 0){
       return Zibonacci((num - 1) / 2) + Zibonacci((num - 3) / 2) + 1;
    }
    if (num > 1 && num % 2 == 0) {
       return Zibonacci(num / 2) + Zibonacci((num + 2) / 2) + 1;
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(i, Zibonacci(i));
}
```

Comment: thanks, I've been stuck for hours.

I thought Zib(2n+1) == Zib(n) + Zib(n-1)+1 was the formula for odd numbers and was equivalent to:

if(num%2 != 0){
       Zib(n) + Zib(n-1)+1;
    }

Yup, my mistake. Not enough brain processing power, I need more practice...

Answer (score 1):

@trincot is correct, you have to rewrite the recursive equations in terms of *z(n)*. You can use [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) for the rest -

1. if *n* is negative, throw an error (optional)
2. (inductive) *n* is non-negative. if *n* is less than 3, return *max(1,n)*
3. (inductive) *n* is greater than 2. if *n* is odd, return *z((n - 1) / 2) + z((n - 1) / 2 - 1) + 1*
4. (inductive) *n* is greater than 2 and even. return *z(n / 2) + z(n / 2 + 1) + 1*

```js
function z(n) {
  if (n < 0)
    throw Error
  else if (n < 3)
    return Math.max(1, n)
  else if (n & 1)
    return z((n - 1) / 2) + z((n - 1) / 2 - 1) + 1
  else
    return z(n / 2) + z(n / 2 + 1) + 1
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  console.log(i, z(i))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```
0 1
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 6
5 4
6 10
7 6
8 11
9 10
```

We can also write *z* as a pure functional expression -

```js
const z = n => // n for all n >= 0
  n < 3
    ? Math.max(1, n)                            // base
    : n & 1
      ? z((n - 1) / 2) + z((n - 1) / 2 - 1) + 1 // odd
      : z(n / 2) + z(n / 2 + 1) + 1             // even

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  console.log(i, z(i))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```
0 1
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 6
5 4
6 10
7 6
8 11
9 10
```